# Third party SMS messaging apps stop BroadcastReceiver from receiving SMS messages

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm making an Android app that automatically responds to incoming SMS messages. It detects incoming SMS messages with a `BroadcastReceiver` as follows in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.SMSBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

where `SMSBroadcastReceiver` is as follows

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // code here to deal with message etc.
    }
}
```

**This is all working and fine.** The problem occurs when I install [Facebook Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca) and check both "Turn On Text Messaging" and "Use as main texting App" like so:

[image: facebook screencapture]

With these settings `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` is now never called, and so for people who use this or another 3rd party SMS app, my app doesn't work!

### Progress so far

I've realised it may be the case that `abortBroadcast();` is being called by fbook before it gets to my application if it's got a higher priority, but I've set priority to the [maximum of 1000](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY) already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've realised it may be the case that abortBroadcast(); is being called by fbook before it gets to my application if it's got a higher priority, but I've set priority to the maximum of 1000 already.

That's not the maximum. That's what the documentation says is the maximum. The maximum is 2,147,483,647 or so (maximum positive integer).

It is impractical for you to have higher priority than every other SMS client, simply because anyone can declare theirs to be the maximum. Simply advise your users that other SMS apps may interfere with yours.

Comment: I tried this shortly after posting the question and you're right. Setting the priority to the maximum integer works a treat. Since my app doesn't call `abortBroadcast()` and doesn't interfere in any way I assume that this can't cause any troubles with other apps? Could mine still be outdone by an app with the same max priority?

Comment: @GeorgePowell: "I assume that this can't cause any troubles with other apps?" -- in theory, you are correct. "Could mine still be outdone by an app with the same max priority?" -- yes. I do not know what the tiebreaker is.

Comment: Tie breaker is supposed to be determined based off of install order.  This whole area is pretty cloudy though in android.  Nothing seems to really work as documented.  Apps like handcent sms manage to screw everyone over.